# Can a particular instance of a class declared in a python file be accessed from another file?

Tags: python

I have a class which have several functions in it. In file1, I have created an instance of that class.

```
class requestHandler():
  def __init__(self):
       ......

  def processRequest(self,command):
       ......
if __name__ == "__main__" :
   currentHandler = requestHandler()
```

Now, I want to access this 'currentHandler' instance from another file. I have tried several ways, but have been failed. If I try like this:

```
import file1

class adapter:
    def __init__(self):
         command = "move"
         .......

    def processRequest(self):
         d = file1.requestHandler()
         d.processRequest(command)
```

It creates a new instance of 'requestHandler' class. But I do not want that.

Can someone please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is currentHander defined in the `__name__ == "__main__"` block? You should create the instance at the module level. Then you can reference the instance simply as `file1.currentHandler`.

Comment: Doing so creates a new instance of the class, does not allow to access the one created by file1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python programs come in two basic flavors: *scripts* - which are the top level programs you run from the command line, by clicking them, etc... and modules, which are imported. A python program is one *script* named `__main__` and any number of imported modules (typically named by the program's file name).

Your *file1.py* could be either a script or a module, depending on how you run it. However, with your `if __name__ == "__main__"` statement tells us that the object you want is only created when *file1.py* is run as a top level script.

Now we have a problem. If you import a top level script, you get a second independent copy of the script and none of the stuff you created in the script is available in the imported version.

So what do you do about it? Well, the first thing is to step back and look at the design of your project. You should generally put stuff you want to share in modules, not scripts. You don't want modules to take actions like creating a `requestHandler` just because the file was imported. But a factory method would work well.

So, create a module (that is, a python program that is visible somewhere in the python path)

*requesthandler.py*

```
import threading

class requestHandler():
  def __init__(self):
       ......

  def processRequest(self,command):
       ......

_common_request_handler = None
_common_request_handler_lock = threading.Lock()

def get_request_handler():
    global _common_request_handler
    with _common_request_handler_lock:
        if not _common_request_hander:
            _common_request_hander = requestHandler()
    return _common_request_handler
```

Now the top level script or any other molude can

```
import requesthandler
handler = requesthandler.get_request_handler()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Your process seems much better and efficient. I will try to design the project like you have specified.

Comment: Nice solution. Had this singleton implementation in mind but he said he couldn't update the requestHandler.. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your handler instance to the adapter class

```
from file2 import adapter

class requestHandler():
  def __init__(self):
       ......

  def processRequest(self, command):
       ......

if __name__ == "__main__" :
   currentHandler = requestHandler()
   a = adapter()
   a.processRequest(currentHandler)
```

..

```
class adapter:
    def __init__(self):
         command = "move"
         .......

    def processRequest(self, handler):
        # You now have a reference to that instance within this method
        doWork(handler)
```

Comment: the thing is, I cannot call the adapter class from file1, it has to be other way around -  i need to access the handler instance from the second file i.e. from adapter class

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if you can read an instance from memory into a new object without passing it between classes. I'm sure there's probably some hacky solution to do so but I'll have to keep my eye on this thread in case someone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use currentHandler from another script,

```
currentHandler = requestHandler()
```

must not be under the:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

statement. It must be outside the if statement.

Example:

file1

```
class a():
    def f(self):
        print 4
b = a()
```

console:

import file1

file1.b.f()

4

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried your way, but it creates a new instance of the class, does not allow to access the one created by file1.

Comment: The example was missing an argument: def f(self) but the logic is ok. It works as you asked. b instance is created at the import time.